# Load the previous data from text file into a new system

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

Here is my code:

```
public boolean readFromFileBooking()
    {
       boolean isFileBooking = true;
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bookings.txt"));   
            String data = reader.readLine();   
            if (data == null)   
            {
                System.out.println("No Bookings Have Been Made . . . .");
            }    
 data = reader.readLine();  
 reader.close();            
}
```

Here is the sequence:

1. Write array into a text file
2. Stop/exit from the system
3. On restart load the previous array in the text file so it can be used again.

The problem is whenever I start a new system, the text file will be overwritten by a new array. Actually I want the new array become a new list in `ArrayList`.

Can you guys share to me how to load the previous data in a new system? How to load/copy the previous data in text file?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post the code otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Please post the code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: *"The problem is whenever I start a new system, the text file will be overwritten by a new array."* If you mean 'on exit' then I don't see the problem.  Otherwise, what do you mean?

Comment: BTW - your post seemed slightly illogical so I edited it, but am not sure I caught the right intent.  Please review my changes carefully.

Comment: How about using the (command line) arguments to main to switch between writing and reading the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will write out an array of integers into a file with each number separated by a space. It will then read them back in and store them as an arraylist. I have ignored the exception handling to focus on the IO.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
    writeOut(array);
    List<Integer> list = readIn();
    for (Integer num : list) {
        System.out.print(num + " " );
    }
}

public static List<Integer> readIn() {
    final File file = new File("file.txt");
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(scan.nextInt());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return list;
}

public static void writeOut(int[] array) {
    final File file = new File("file.txt");

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            writer.write(Integer.toString(array[i]) + " ");
        }
        writer.close();
        writer.flush();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't attempt to read and write from the file at the same time.

On startup, read the file if its there and when finished close it.

On shutdown, write the file and close it when finished.

If you attempt to read and write to the file (without appending) you will truncate the file and there will be nothing to read.